# jQuery Data Table Error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, jquery

While working on jQuery DataTable(AJAX request) I see below error in console, can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
GET http://www.someurl.com/page/someservice?callback=jQuery2140051484344992786646_1438166663698&_=1438166663699 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED    jQuery.min.js:4
```

jQuery Code

```
var url = "http://www.someurl.com/page/someservice", // dummy url
    authToken = "afdaafd1122q200afdjaslfdjalf", // dummy data
    oTable = $('#daSelector').dataTable( {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": url,
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": 'jsonp',
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "headers": {
                        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + authToken
                    }
                },
                "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "Services" }
                ]
    });
```

Comment: Looks like DNS can't resolve `www.someurl.com` (whatever the real value of it is). Have you verified the URL by copy-pasting it into the address bar of your browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://www.someurl.com/page/someservice", // dummy url
    authToken = "afdaafd1122q200afdjaslfdjalf", // dummy data

$.ajax({
   "url": url,
   "type": "GET",
   "dataType": 'jsonp',
   "serverSide": true,
   "sAjaxDataProp": "",
   "headers": {
      'Authorization': 'bearer ' + authToken
   },
   "success": function (json) {
       $('#daSelector').dataTable(json);
   }  
});
```